# How to connect symfony 5 DATABASE_URL (in .env) in a container to a wamp on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, docker, symfony, symfony5

I have a project that I develop with Symfony for my enterprise.
The solution for bypassing the VPN is to use a docker container.

**The situation :**

My application is running in a container but I develop on my local computer (I mean no WSL).
I have a wamp installed on my localhost and the goal is to configure the DATABASE_URL in .env in Symfony to my wamp.

I don't have any docker.compose.ymal in my files, I use this command line
`docker run -ti --rm=true -p 8000:8000 -v %CD%:/opt/src [repo]/base-php74-tools:latest /bin/bash`

Obviously, I replaced [repo] by the repository I connect but I write this for being anonyme.

In my `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host`, I have these lines :

[image: My host docker]

So when I use : `DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@10.4.24.163:3306/keuken?serverVersion=5.7"`

It works well but that's not efficient because the IP is dynamic.
So I tried to use the DNS name:
`DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@host.docker.internal:3306/keuken?serverVersion=5.7"`

And I have this error :
[image]

I suppose that's because Symfony wait for an IP but the IP change dynamically... That's not efficient...

What can I do for connecting my symfony containerized to my wamp on my localhost?

Comment: `host.docker.internal` points to host IP, not to some external IP (basically `host.docker.internal === localhost`). Also ensure that your `host.docker.internal` actually resolves to some IP address, because not all dockers has it. Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: @Justinas Ok I got it and thought about this but when I use the IP associated to "Host.docker.internal", it works... why? Normally it shouldn't. And is it possible to find the localhost IP inside the container?

Comment: @Justinas I am a windows user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's better to go through a container manager like docker-compose. Ideally, a container only serves a single task

The docker-compose.yaml file might look like this :

```
version: '3.7'


services:

    mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    image: mysql:5.7 # or 8.0 
    restart: always

    php-app:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: /path/to/php/dockerfile
    container_name: php-apache2
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/app
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll check to create a docker-compose.yaml, do you use docker compose up for launching this file?

Comment: Yes, "docker-compose up" is good command for launch this file